# How to get the log messages in the order I need?

Tags: javascript, express, knex.js

How do I prevent `Service running ...` msg from getting logged first? I would like the messages inside `testDBConnection` fn. to be logged first instead. When DB is not running I would like the `Looks like DB is not running` msg to be kept getting logged and once the DB kicks in the `DB connection has been established` and `Service running ...` msgs should follow. I tried multiple things, but I was not able to come up with proper code. Thanks for your help.

index.js

```
import app from './config/express';
import config from './config/config';
import logger from './config/winston';
import { initDbConnection } from './server/db';

app.listen(config.port, () => {
  initDbConnection();
  logger.info(`Service running and listening on port ${config.port}`);
});
```

db.js

```
import knex from 'knex';
import config from '../config/config';
import logger from '../config/winston';

const { db } = config;
let pool;

const testDBConnection = (client) => {
  const intervalId = setInterval(async () => {
    try {
      await client.select(1);
      logger.info('DB connection has been established');
      clearInterval(intervalId);
    } catch (error) {
      logger.error('Looks like DB is not running');
    }
  }, 2000);
};

export const initDbConnection = (mock) => {
  if (mock) {
    pool = knex({});
  } else {
    pool = knex({
      client: 'pg',
      version: '7.4.2',
      connection: db,
      debug: true
    });
    testDBConnection(pool);
  }
};

export const getDb = () => pool;
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use async/await for that.

```
import app from './config/express';
import config from './config/config';
import logger from './config/winston';
import { initDbConnection } from './server/db';

app.listen(config.port, async () => {
  await initDbConnection();
  logger.info(`Service running and listening on port ${config.port}`);
});
```

db.js:

```
import knex from 'knex';
import config from '../config/config';
import logger from '../config/winston';

const { db } = config;
let pool, connected;

const testDBConnection = (client) => {
   return new Promise(resolve => {
   const intervalId = setInterval(async () => {
        try {
          await client.select(1);
          if (connected) {
              return;
          }
          connected = true;

          logger.info('DB connection has been established');
          clearInterval(intervalId);
          resolve('success');
        } catch (error) {
          logger.error('Looks like DB is not running');
        }
      }, 2000);
   });
};

export const initDbConnection = (mock) => {
  if (mock) {
    pool = knex({});
  } else {
    pool = knex({
      client: 'pg',
      version: '7.4.2',
      connection: db,
      debug: true
    });
    return testDBConnection(pool);
  }
};

export const getDb = () => pool;
```

This way, the logger inside the app.listen cb won't be called until the initDbConnection is resolved. Another way would be to just use the promise `then`.

Comment: OK, we are almost there. It works fine in case DB is running before the service is started. However, when DB is off initially and then the service is started this is what I see in the console: `error: Looks like DB is not running` `error: Looks like DB is not running` `error: Looks like DB is not running` `info: DB connection has been established` `info: Service running and listening on port 8080` `info: DB connection has been established` `info: DB connection has been established` As you see, the DB connection has been established msg is printed multiple times.

Comment: The most probably reason why this double print has happened is, that there were two `client.select(1);` requests running (e.g. two intervals that were not finished) when the DB was complete. Look at my edit to see a possible solution. Please note I do not disclose a full or best practice solution - just a main technique to handle this.  For instance, it might be you'd like to call `testDBConnection` several times, and then you'd still have an interval running so in this case, move the logger and the `connected` if to the bottom. Hope this helps.

Comment: How come there were 2 `client.select(1)` queries running? Can the scheduled functions within `setInterval` run in parallel? If you could elaborate a bit on what runs when I'd be grateful. I am a bit confused about the combination of promises, async/await and setInterval. Thanks.

Comment: Has the flag fix solved the issue? If so, then the case was this:
one interval called `client.select(1)`. Two seconds passed, and another `client.select(1)` was called. In the meantime, the `client.select(1)` promise resolved for both. Here's the flow to make it clearer:
```
1) setInterval
2) Interval1
3) Interval2
4) Interval 1 - rejected due to DB timeout 
5) Interval 3
6) DB active
7) Interval 2 and 3 resolved successfully (initiating the logger)
```
Hope this is clearer.